# Call function when Animation finish in Swift

Tags: swift, animation

I have an animation that start with the app. When this animation finish, I need to call another function, but I don't find the process to do it.

This is my animation code:

```
func bettyAnimation(){

var betty: UIImageView = UIImageView()

var bettyImageList: [UIImage] = []

for i in 1...77{
    let imageName = "pantalla_02_betty_\(i).png"
    bettyImageList += [UIImage(named: imageName)!]
}

self.view.addSubview(betty)
betty.animationRepeatCount=1
betty.animationImages = bettyImageList
betty.animationDuration = 6.0

betty.startAnimating()
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the code inside the `completion` block.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(
  // duration
  1.0,
  // delay
  delay: 0.0, 
  options: nil, 
  animations: {

   // put animation code here

  }, completion: {finished in

   // the code you put here will be executed when your animation finishes, therefore
   // call your function here 
  }
)
```